# How can I recreate Grant's signature sound using a vocoder on a synthesizer?

Tags: synthesizer, replication, electronic-music, vocoder

So there is a music artist named Grant, and in most of his songs there is a signature style of sound design that he uses, and I am almost 100% sure he just runs synths (sometimes guitars) through a vocoder to create these sounds.  They are not all the same sound, but the general feel of them and how they are made is the same.  How can I recreate them?

Here are some examples:

(probably the best example, the lead is the epitome of this sound style.   The pluck chords in the verses are representative as well)

(pretty much the whole song uses these sounds)

(the chorus has a very bassy sounding vocoder chord)

**PART 1 FOR THIS SONG**

**PART 2 FOR THIS SONG**

(same thing as  the wishes)

Thanks if you can help, I've been in love with these sounds for years, and now that I've been getting into more experimental sound design, I want to try new techniques/replicating interesting sounds.

Comment: Great question, looking forward to the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it sounds like he's applying FL Studio's Vocodex plugin. Although I'm not a specialist using this I know that you can do some insane stuff with it utilizing a "carry"-layer and a sound-layer so that the sound from the sound layer is vocoded using the MIDI-information coming from the carry-layer.

Two really good tutorials on how to use the plugin properly can be found here:

and here:

---

If I remember correctly this old FL Studio demo track also made use of this technique to layer the vocals (which where only a single vocal line) as chords:

(I'm not entirely sure if it really was this track and I'll update my post as soon as I have time to research this properly, however there definitely is a FL demo track which makes use of this technique).